# How to import ALL tickers from investing.com to Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

I waste a lot of time tumbling from one country list of stocks (on investing.com) to another looking for stocks to buy.

How can I aggregate stocks from all countries (and exchanges) to one sheet, with selected parameters (say market cap and 1 month perf.)?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a standard way to export data from investing.com, you will need to write a scraper that pulls all of the data from the website that you want, and then use google sheets API (or some other method) to import it into your workbook.

This scraper can then be scheduled to run automatically so that you don't need to update your workbook.

Now, for the sake of legality because of course I promote ethical scripting, you will have to check whether you have permission to scrape this data, as many platforms don't allow this because they have rights to the data.

Re: terms and conditions from investing.com

> The Services may not be used or accessed by any automated machine, bot, spider, or such other automated feature or service;

Comment: Thanks! Can I do such a 'worldwide' listing using Yahoo or Google Finance ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with those platforms so I don't have an answer.